# Automated messaging or redirection

Tags: 2010, list, email

I'm working on creating a simple form list on my team's SharePoint site where team members can submit improvement ideas and/or feedback (kind of like a virtual suggestion box). So far, I've created the custom form list where I can track the items that are submitted. So here is my question: Is there a way to have an automated message pop up after a new item has been submitted? (Something like, "Thank you for your feedback!"). Right now, if something is submitted on the form, it takes the user back to the list (which I don't want others to see). Or can SharePoint be programmed so that when a user submits a new item to a list using the form, that it automatically directs them to a separate "Thank You" page? Is this possible?

Alternatively, can the user be redirected back to the site home page after submitting their form and then receive a confirmation/"thank you" email in Outlook?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can override "_CorrectUrlForRefreshPageSubmitForm" Java script function of SharePoint's Core.js.

You can find this :
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\core.js

Please refer this link for best practice that how to override core.js
https://yoursandmyideas.wordpress.com/2011/10/30/customize-or-override-core-js-file-functions-in-sharepoint/

You can also refer this link : 
https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/custom-redirect-after-creating-a-new-sharepoint-item/

to override specified form functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are opening the new item form from a custom page or providing a link somewhere, you can handle redirection on submit via the `Source` parameter in the URL query string.

Just set it to the page you wish to redirect to:

```
<new item page link>?source=<link for page to redirect after submit>
```